# Safely Removing an AdView from a LinearLayout for Ad Free Users

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, adview

I have an Android App with a Banner Ad in it. I only put in the AdView element into the LinearLayout after I have checked ads are meant to be displayed.

However, the user can purchase NoAds during the run time of the program. This means I have to safely stop the ad and remove the Adview from the program without falling foul of Admob rules where you cannot hide adverts.

Here is my code, but I am very unsure about the section in the `if` statement on the line `if (mAdView != null) { // It might not be created yet`.

**Is that just hiding it, not removing it completely?:**

```
public void turnAdvertsOnOff(boolean on) {
    advertsOn = on;

    // IMPORTANT - changes to layout must be done on the UI Thread or will get error
    m_Context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LinearLayout myLayout;
            // NEW
            //AdView mAdView;

            myLayout = (LinearLayout) m_Context.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
            //mAdView = (AdView) m_Context.findViewById(R.id.adView);

            if(advertsOn){
                if(mAdView == null && myLayout != null) {
                    // Create it and add it to the LinearLayout
                    mAdView = new AdView(m_Context);
                    // Sizes BANNER, SMART_BANNER, LARGE_BANNER
                    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                    mAdView.setAdUnitId(adIdBanner);
                    myLayout.addView(mAdView);
                }
                if (mAdView != null) mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                if (mAdView != null) { // It might not be created yet
                    mAdView.pause();
                    mAdView.setEnabled(false);
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //mAdView.destroy();
                    //mAdView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //mAdView.pause();
                    //mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }});
}
```

Comment: You need to talk to a representative of AdMob or a lawyer familiar with their terms of service.  We can't know what they'll count as hiding or not, and questions about terms of service of app stores/libraries/etc are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is to `remove()` the `AdView` from its parent.

Why not set Visibility to GONE?

If you set the visibility to GONE, the AdView will still request the Ad Servers to fill in the Ads, so its better to completely remove the `AdView`.

For example - 

Add the AdView in you layout file, if the User has removed the Ads via IAP, just call `myLayout.removeView(mAdView);`

Also there's no need to call `runOnUiThread()` if you are calling `turnAdvertsOnOff()` from the ui thread.

Comment: This is the answer. You are also right, `turnAdvertsOnOff()` is **not** being run on the ui thread. It took me ages to find out why it was throwing an exception and why I needed to use `runOnUiThread()`.